# Dividing COUNT (strings) with conditions in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm pretty new to SQL and Google BigQuery, so forgive me if this is a really stupid question.
I've got a table where a string column is called "status" and there are different kinds of entries - opened, clicked, sent, etc. I want to divide the number of occurrences where status was "clicked" by the number of occurrences where status was "opened". I was trying something like this:

SELECT
COUNT(properties.status)
FROM
`campaign`
WHERE
properties.status = "clicked"
/
SELECT
COUNT(properties.status)
FROM
`campaign`
WHERE
properties.status = "opened"

Comment: select count(this) / count(that) from ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `case` *expressions* to do *conditional aggregation*.

```
SELECT SUM(case when properties.status = "clicked" then 1 else 0 end) /
       SUM(case when properties.status = "opened" then 1 else 0 end)
FROM campaign
```

Answer (score 1):

In BigQuery, you can use `COUNTIF()`:

```
SELECT COUNTIF(properties.status = 'clicked') / COUNTIF(properties.status = 'opened')
FROM campaign c;
```

If you want to handle divide by zero (so it returns `NULL` rather than an error), use either `NULLIF()` or `SAFE_DIVIDE()`:

```
SELECT COUNTIF(properties.status = 'clicked') / NULLIF(COUNTIF(properties.status = 'opened'), 0)
FROM campaign c;
```

Or:

```
SELECT SAFE_DIVIDE(COUNTIF(properties.status = 'clicked'),
                   COUNTIF(properties.status = 'opened')
                  )
FROM campaign c;
```